# Error when calling my Firebase function. TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:39

Tags: firebase, properties, cors, typeerror

I have written a Firebase function and got it deployed to Firebase.
The steps i have taken to deploy are -

1. Inside my local project root folder, i ran "firebase init", which subsequently created functions folder.
2. cd functions. Then run "npm install --save firebase-admin firebase-functions cors"
3. Modified index.js to suit my own function named storePostData().
4. go back to my root folder via cd ..
5. run "firebase deploy"
6. Verified that function been uploaded and created in my Firebase Functions panel.

index.js

---

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true, });

exports.storePostData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors((request, response) => {

    admin.database().ref('posts').push({
      id: request.body.id,
      title: request.body.title,
      location: request.body.location,
      image: request.body.image
    })
      .then(() => {
        response.status(201).json({message: 'Data stored', id: request.body.id});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        response.status(500).json({error: err});
      });

  });
});
```

---

My problem is, whenever i try calling my firebase function, say, as in fetch('https://us-central1-.cloudfunctions.net/storePostData', mypost), i will hit error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:39".

I am at my wits end, and have googled extensively, ..., has anyone hit this error before and manage to solve it?

rgds,
newbie

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should test your functions first with `firebase serve --only functions`. Also i see your are not initializing firebase with `admin.initializeApp()`

Answer (score 0):

```
cors((req, res) => {})
```

this is incorrect

```
cors(req, res, () => {})
```

this is correct

cors take three arguments, the call back take no argument